# How to make Vue auto-instantiate components on init?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to Vue, I'm doing some tests.

```
Vue.component('area-selectors-box', {
  template: `
    <div class="selectors-box">
      <select v-for="select in selects">
        <option>test</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  `,
  props:['selects']
});

var dealer_manager = new Vue({
  el: '#dealers-main-box'
  ,data:{
    dealers:[],
    selects:[{name:'select-1'},{name:'select-2'}]
  }
  ,mounted: function(){
  }
  ,created: function(){
  }
  ,methods: {

  }
});
```

...And later in html:

```
<area-selectors-box></area-selectors-box>
```

But it will only output `<div class="selectors-box"></div>`, not the selects.

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check your props, are you passing any data to the 'selects' prop?

Comment: Selects is populated with fake values as you can see. Do you mean in the html?

Comment: Maybe something like: `<area-selectors-box v-bind:selects="selects"></area-selectors-box>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank to @Daniel Danaee, I found out I missed a step. On my html I had to reference the binded property like this:

```
<area-selectors-box v-bind:selects="selects"></area-selectors-box>
```

Comment: Awesome.  You can even do `<area-selectors-box :selects="selects"></area-selectors-box>`

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad :) If you ever encounter rendering issues, speaking from experience with JS frameworks, often its the data not being able to be found or loaded. Good luck!